# Vim - ftplugin settings changes not updating for existing file

Tags: vim, ftplugin

It seems like there's some odd caching-like behavior going on for files that I have already opened once in Vim.  I have a file `foo.txt` that I opened, and then I change some of the settings in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/text.vim`, but those new settings do not appear in `foo.txt`.  I can quit vim and reopen `foo.txt`, or reload with `:e`, or even `:so ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/text.vim`, but none of these seem to have an effect on `foo.txt`'s settings.  If I `mv foo.txt bar.txt`, the settings show up for `bar.txt` with no issues.

**EDIT**

It seems I can force the settings to reload for `foo.txt` with the following sequence:

1. `:so ~/.vimrc`
2. `:so ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/text.vim`

Questions:

1. Why is this necessary / why were the other settings not picked up?
2. Why was sourcing `~/.vimrc` not enough?  It applied settings that were directly specified in `~/.vimrc`, but shouldn't the ftplugins have been loaded at the line `filetype plugin indent on`?  Why was sourcing `text.vim` afterwards necessary?

Answer (score 2):

Vim [runtime](https://github.com/vim/vim/tree/master/runtime) consists of a few hundred files, I'm not sure why you expect Vim to monitor them continuously.  It doesn't.  These files are loaded at some well-defined (and documented) points, that's all there is to it.

In particular there is no *safe* way to reload your configuration.  You can do things like `:so ~/.vimrc`, but unless you specifically wrote your `vimrc` to take that into account, there *will* be drawbacks (such as `autocmd`s piling up).  If you want to be safe you have to quit Vim and start it again.  That's how Vim works.

Now, for `ftplugin`s you might get away with something like this:

```
:setf text
```

(use the actual filetype instead of `text`).  This works for simple `set fubar` options.  It works because under the hood `setf` is actually a carefully written `autocmd`.  It still breaks for more complicated constructs (such as `autocmd`s or file-scoped variables), for the same reasons `:so ~/.vimrc` has drawbacks.

Answer (score 1):

A few more precisions:

- `.vimrc` is loaded once -> for defining global stuff
- same thing with `.gvimrc`, loaded only with gvim after the `.vimrc`
- plugins are loaded once as well, after the vimrc files -> for global stuff as well
- autoloaded plugins are loaded on demand, once, whenever a function they define is invoked
- ftplugins are loaded once per buffer (and possibly multiple times! as there may be multiple buffers requiring them to be sourced) -> for definitions that shall apply only to the current buffer that triggered its loading
- there are also langmap scripts, syntax scripts, indentation scripts, and even the old `macros/` scripts (loaded explicitly/manually)
- some plugins provides *local vimrcs* (basically identical to ftplugins, but loaded depending on the current directory of a buffer, instead of its filetype).

As you see, all things are loaded once, only. If you want to load them several times, you'll have to do it manually and explicitly. That's why a few of us have a `:Reload` command that simplifies reloading any kind of script - mine is hidden in my collection of scripts: lh-misc -> plugin/vim-maintain.vim

Comment: One of the main problems with Vim docs (if not THE main one) is the lack of a high-level view of how things fit together.  For this reason, everybody has to discover this kind of details by parsing them bottom-up, which is why the vast majority of people give up even before trying.  I wonder is there is anything we can do about that.

Comment: @SatoKatsura. We used to have vim tips, then migrated to vim.wikia.com. A lot of effort had been invested to sort out the various tips, edit them... John and Fritz, among others, did a terrific work on this topic. Unfortunately wikia isn't well liked. Partly because of the intrusive ads when we aren't logged in, partly because we've never found the time to finish, and complete the tips database. And also it suffers SO/SE policy of no external links. As a consequence, we almost have to start over, it doesn't help capitalizing knowledge. So now, we have the vim documentation on SO...